# Why does 1m.ToString() return a different result than 1.0m.ToString()?

Tags: .net, .net-core

If I initialize a decimal number without decimal place, `ToString` returns the number without decimal places:

`1m.ToString()` results in "1".

But if I initialize a decimal number with .0, I get .0 in the string:

`1.0m.ToString()` results in "1.0"

Can someone explain what the reason for this is?

Comment: Hmmm.  Both examples are :"real literals". Both are "decimal" reals ("m").  The decimal literal with a decimal point prints  "1.0", and the decimal literal without the decimal point prints "1"..  It "makes sense" ... but I couldn't find any explanation as to "why":either [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#the-decimal-type) or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the decimal values 1m and 1.0m look the same for a human and have the same value, they are encoded differently.

Using the sample code for the `decimal.GetBits()` method on page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=netcore-3.0 you will get this result.

```
Argument     Bits[3]   Bits[2]   Bits[1]   Bits[0]
--------     -------   -------   -------   -------
       1    00000000  00000000  00000000  00000001
     1,0    00010000  00000000  00000000  0000000A
```

The `decimal.ToString()` reflects these differences and produces different results.

More on about the binary encoding of decimals are available on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?view=netcore-3.0

Answer (score 3):

That's because in .Net, `System.Decimal` keeps it's trailing zeros.

As stated in the [remarks section of System.Decimal official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> ...The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.